Fixed point theorem on an open ball in complete metric space
Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space, $a \in X$ and $r>0$. Let $f:O(a,r)→X$ be a contraction with a contraction constant $L$, $d(f(x),f(y))<Ld(x,y)$, for all $x,y \in O(a,r)$ and $d(f(a),a) \le \alpha r$. If $\alpha = 1-L$, can we prove that the function $f$ has a unique fixed point in  $O(a,r)$, or is there a counterexample?
It is easy to prove that when $0<\alpha < 1-L$, the function $f$ has a unique fixed point in  $O(a,r)$. But $\alpha = 1-L$ seems difficult for me.
I find a similar question here, but it is a little different.

Did you check in the book Fixed Point Theory by Granas and Dugundji?

A little less general, but corollary 1.2 of that book answers that $f$ must have a fixed point if $d(f(a), a)\leq \alpha r$ is replaced by $d(f(a), a) < \alpha r$.

Oh yes I have solved it! Thank you very much!

I have come up with another question. If  $d(f(x),f(y))<Ld(x,y)$ is changed into $d(f(x),f(y)) \le Ld(x,y)$, is it still true?

That's not true when $d(f(x),f(y))<Ld(x,y)$ is changed into $d(f(x),f(y))\leq Ld(x,y)$.
For a counterexample, let $r=1, L=\alpha=\frac{1}{2}, X =[0, 1],a=0$ where $X$ is equipped with Euclidean metric.
Define $f:O(0, 1)\to X$ by $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}x$, then $f$ satisfies the conditions, but $f$ doesn't have a fixed point in $O(0,1) = [0, 1)$.
